# Python dictionary printing first value and ignore empty

Tags: python, dictionary

An aws lambda function I've written gives me the following dictionary output(Please note the dictionary between "START RequestID & END Request ID ,

```
START RequestId: 74d45fe6-c579-11e8-835d-73465f3bb0f0 Version: $LATEST
{u'd2otag1p96': [[0, 20]], u'k43tbb7nic': [[0, 20]], u'90yuipi22i': [[18, 2]]}
{}
END RequestId: 74d45fe6-c579-11e8-835d-73465f3bb0f0
```

Please can someone tell me how to print just the key and it's first corresponding value and ignore the 2 curly brackets on the third line? i.e  d2otag1p96:0, k43tbb7nic:0, 90yuipi22i:18

Below is what I tried but to no avail. Posting only a part of the code thats relevant to this question. Note the print statement.

```
for uplan in uplans:
        used = (uplan['id'])
        lmt = (uplan['quota']['limit'])
        resp = client.get_usage(keyId='',usagePlanId=(used), startDate=today,endDate=today)['items']
        print(resp.itmes)[0]
```

Comment: That seems to be an empty `dict`. You can check if the `len(your_dict.keys())>0` then only print the values.

Comment: @mad_ thanks a lot. Can you please provide me with a code so that I can better understand.

Answer (score 1):

Suppress printing the empty dict `{}` by testing its length to be not zero. Assuming `dd` to be your dictionary.

```
if len(dd.keys())>0:
    [print(key, value[0][0]) for key, value in dd.items()]
```

gives

```
d2otag1p96 0
k43tbb7nic 0
90yuipi22i 18
```

for

```
dd = dict({u'd2otag1p96': [[0, 20]], u'k43tbb7nic': [[0, 20]], u'90yuipi22i': [[18, 2]]})
```

and nothing for

```
dd = dict{}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Just to confirm I believe I can replace “dd” with “resp” here?  I’m so sorry just that I’m very new to python hence the silly questions.

Comment: if `resp` is your dictionary, then you can try it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are receiving actual `dict` and not `json`. Here is the example to illustrate my point. Just check if the dict is empty or not

```
d={}
if d:
    print('printing dict with values')
    print(d.items()[0])
else:
    print('empty dict')
```

Output:

```
'empty dict'
```

In another example if `dict` contains a key

```
d={u'd2otag1p96': [[0, 20]], u'k43tbb7nic': [[0, 20]], u'90yuipi22i': [[18, 2]]}
if d:
    print('printing dict with values')
    for k,v in d.items():
        print(str(k),v[0][0])
else:
    print('empty dict')
```

Output

```
 printing dict with values
('d2otag1p96', 0)
('k43tbb7nic', 0)
('90yuipi22i', 18)
```